# How to increase pandoc equation resolution

Tags: pandoc, latex-to-word

I have provided a minimal working example below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$x^2$
\end{document}
```

I processed the above LaTeX file using

```
pandoc --webtex -t html | pandoc -f html -o my.docx
```

How can I increase the resolution of the resulting embedded equation in Word when using Pandoc to convert a LaTeX file to a Word file?

Comment: Why not go from TeX to docx directly?

Comment: Indeed as @Werner mentioned `pandoc -s yourdocument.tex -o your.docx` results in a math image with higher resolution.

Comment: @Werner I don't want a direct conversion because Word does not correctly format many of my equations. @Marjin, as far as I can tell, running `pandoc -s yourdocument.tex -o your.docx` does not produce a math image but instead converts mathematical formulae to Word's native math formatting system.

Answer (score 2):

If you absolutely need your formulas as embedded images¹, you have to use a webservice, that lets you specify the output resolution.

One such service is `latex.codecogs.com` (it's pandoc's standard), it lets you define the solution with `\dpi{<value>}` where value can be 50, 80, 100, 110, 120, 150, 200, and 300.

The url to the png generator is: `https://latex.codecogs.com/png.latex?`
The backslash (`\`) has to be replaced by `%5C`. So, if you want 300dpi output, you have to give pandoc the following argument:

```
--webtex='https://latex.codecogs.com/png.latex?%5Cdpi{300}'
```

––

¹Please. Don't.

Comment: Using your command changes the relative size of the equations in the final output. Is it possible to keep the relative size of the equations the same is in the LaTeX code, only changing their resolution?

Comment: @FelixGarner I don't see how. Embedding pictures in word documents is always problematic, do not do it.